# ctrl-v key on AIX

Tags: aix, vi, ksh

I'm new to AIX and I miss some tricks that work well on other *nix flavors.

I need a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> sequence in a ksh scripts, like `^[` (<kbd>CTRL-[</kbd>) and to do that I'm habit to use the <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> , but here it doesn't work.

At the moment I'm obliged to use a windows box with putty so I cannot even edit the scripts on my Linux box and transfer the scripts on the AIX server.

Do you know why and how I can fix the issue?

To resume the answers:

@Dennis:

> there are a few other ways to use
>   escape in a Korn shell script:

```
print '\E' escape1='\033'    # contains the literal characters as shown
echo -e "$escape1"  
printf '%b' "$escape1"  
print "$escape1"
escape2=$'\e'     # contains an actual escape  
echo "$escape2"  
printf '%s' "$escape2"  
print "$escape2"
```

> For the terminal colors
>
> `man 5 terminfo`
>
> $'' notation allow ANSI-C escaping:
>
> `green=$'\e[01;32m'`
>
> It may be that ksh88 don't support $''

I use a ksh88, but I can switch to ksh93.

```
ctrl-v on command line
Version M-11/16/88i 

/usr/dt/bin/dtksh
print ${.sh.version}
Version M-12/28/93d

green=$'\e[01;32m' doesn't give me any error on ksh88,
```

but it doesn't expand the escape sequence.
On ksh93 `$''` the same issue

```
green="$'\e[01;32m'"
```

Using uppercase `E` solved the issue (weird!!!):

```
print $'\E[01;32m hello'
```

To summarize:

```
\E  works
\e  NO
\033    works just with echo
^[     ^v^[ do not work at all
```

Comment: As the comments below are hidden by default, I found out that it works with:

print $'\E[01;32m hello' ((( Not with \e )))

Comment: Try `green=$(printf '\033[32m'); echo "${green}Hello"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
stty -a
```

and see if `lnext` is `^V`. If not, try:

```
stty lnext ^V
```

where you will type "^" (caret) and "V" as separate characters. Now try to see if you can type an escape using `^V^[` (does `^VEsc` work on your keyboard?).

Also, check to see if you're in emacs mode

Depending on how you're using it, there are a few other ways to use escape in a Korn shell script:

```
print '\E'
escape1='\033'    # contains the literal characters as shown
echo -e "$escape1"
printf '%b' "$escape1"
print "$escape1"
escape2=$'\e'     # contains an actual escape
echo "$escape2"
printf '%s' "$escape2"
print "$escape2"
```

Of course, you wouldn't normally output escape all by itself.

Comment: Good point Dennis, lnext was set correctly but I was in emacs mode.
So I solved the issue as you advised as follow:

blue="\\033[01;32m"
green="\\033[01;34m"
cyan="\\033[01;36m"
white="\\033[0m"

export PS1="$(echo ${blue})${USER}@$(echo ${green})${HOST%%.*} $(echo ${cyan})${PWD##*/} $(echo ${white}) "


THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @antenore: If you use the `$''` form, you won't have to use all those `echo` commands: `blue=$'\e[01;32m'`, etc., and `PS1="$blue$USER@ ...` (except that on my system 32 gives me green and 34 gives me blue). Ctrl-V should work in emacs mode, btw, but it's better to use a representative form of control characters instead of a literal form. Another way to set up your colors: `blue=$(tput setaf 4)` (see `man 5 terminfo` for a list of color numbers).

Comment: @Dennis tnx, I've tried it but it doesn't work and I cannot find out why. The only way to use escape sequences inside a VAR is to use the echo... That's really weird. Well my problem is solved, but not my need to know.

Comment: Does `blue=$'\e[01;32m'` give you an error message? It may be that you're running ksh88 and it may not support `$''`. Or is something else happening?

Comment: So, blue is green, sorry for the mistake. 
I'm doing all the test on a Solaris host at the moment, anyway I've the same issues. 
I use a ksh88, but I can switch to ksh93.
Version M-11/16/88i (ctrl-v on command line).
/usr/dt/bin/dtksh

print ${.sh.version}   Version M-12/28/93d

green=$'\e[01;32m' doesn't give me any error on ksh88, but it doesn't expand the escape sequence. On ksh93 $'' the same green="$'\e[01;32m'"

Comment: @antenore: Part of your comment apparently got cut off. If you're using double quotes around it, too, it's not going to work.

Comment: On ksh93 with $'' I have the same issue, it prints just the code inside the parenthesis.
So far the first solution is the only one the works as expected.

Comment: Weird, but this is the solution:

print $'\E[01;32m hello'

Answer (score 2):

If I recall with AIX, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> escape sequence should work, however I remember too that the default TERM in AIX wasn't always what you would expect. Check your `$TERM` variable.  If it's weird:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

or

```
export TERM=vt100
```

If your `$TERM` is wrong, then even if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> might not do anything.  It's a VT100 sequence.

Comment: I thought was that as well, but no luck. I found that to do the ^V I must hold the ctrl also while I'm pressing the V, for the [ it still doesn't work. I have a Swiss keyboard so to digit the [ I need to hold the alt-gr key

Comment: the keystroke should be ctrl-v ctrl-[, I just tried it with the german keyboard layout and it doesn't work for me either(!).  Switching back to the EN(US) layout, I can type the combination okay.  (the German combination for ctrl-[ being ctrl-altgr-8 )

Comment: In the swiss qwertz keyboard the [ is on the left of the p (with è and ü holding the alt-gr), still the same issue... I think I'll add a second keyboard with a US layout... much better to work on *nix environments.